# Javascript and ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made this javascript/ajax but it's not working and I don't know why.

```
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#btn4').click( function(){ 
        var plano = $('#plano').val();
        var plano = $('#name').val();
        var plano = $('#age').val();
        var plano = $('#identify').val();
        var plano = $('#phone').val();
        var plano = $('#email').val();
        var plano = $('#password').val();
        var plano = $('#endereco').val();
        var plano = $('#cidade').val();
        var plano = $('#cep').val();
        var plano = $('#estado').val();
        var plano = $('#code').val();
        var urlData = "plano=" + plano + "&name=" + name + "&age=" + age + "&identify=" + identify + "&phone=" + phone + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&endereco=" + endereco + "&cidade=" + cidade + "&cep=" + cep + "&estado=" + estado + "&code=" + code;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkout2.php", 
            async: true,
            data: urlData, 
            context: jQuery('#step3'),
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#step2').hide('fast');
                this.append(data);
                $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Can someone help me please? Are there any errors in syntax?

Comment: Why are you using the same variable 'plano' to store the values? The variables you're trying to access after 'name', 'age', etc have not been created.

Comment: your assigning everything to the var plano you need to change the variable names

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? Use the developer tools in your browser. Are the errors in the console? Do you see the request in the Net tab? Does it get the response you expect? jQuery supports an `error` function as well as a `success` function. Add one and look at the arguments. Add console.log statements to see if the code is being run at all.

Comment: your not even using urlData

Comment: I can't believe. All variables with the same name. Sorry.

Comment: If you had bothered to look at the developer tools console, it would have shown you a reference error for trying to use `name` without declaring it.

Comment: hint...save a lot of variable hard coding and use serialize() to get whole form data

Comment: Variables don't have memory, unless you are coding in homoeopathic JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple variables with the same name "plano". You should change them according to their use..

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#btn4').click( function(){ 
        var plano = $('#plano').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var identify = $('#identify').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var endereco = $('#endereco').val();
        var cidade = $('#cidade').val();
        var cep = $('#cep').val();
        var estado = $('#estado').val();
        var code = $('#code').val();
        var urlData = "plano=" + plano + "&name=" + name + "&age=" + age + "&identify=" + identify + "&phone=" + phone + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&endereco=" + endereco + "&cidade=" + cidade + "&cep=" + cep + "&estado=" + estado + "&code=" + code;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkout2.php", 
            async: true,
            data: urlData, 
            context: jQuery('#step3'),
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#step2').hide('fast');
                this.append(data);
                $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Try this and see if it helps. You must be more carefull with copy/pastes ;)